# Rally Cardboard column SDK 2.0rc1 missing displayValue config?

Tags: rally

I am upgrading a cardboard app from SDK 2.0p5 to SDK 2.0rc1. 
I need to add a string that will be displayed in the header of the column. In 2.0p5 I used "displayValue" however this is not available in SDK 2.0rc1. 
How do I work around this problem?

```
        Ext.Array.each(states, function (state) {
             columns.push({
               xtype:'rallycardboardcolumn',
               displayValue:state.get('Name'), //NOT AVAILABLE IN SDK 2.0rc1                   
               value:state.get('_ref'),
               record:state
            });
        });
```

When does Rally recommend upgrading custom apps to the latest SDK ie 2.0rc1?

Answer (score 2):

Using headerTpl in columnHeaderConfig solved the problem.

```
Ext.Array.each(states, function (state) {
           columns.push({
           xtype:'rallycardboardcolumn',                 
           //displayValue:state.get('Name'),
           columnHeaderConfig: {
                headerTpl:  state.get('Name'), 
           },                                                  
           value:state.get('_ref'),
           record:state
          });
  });
```